# missing yamllint package in ci/cd pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am running this CI/CD piece of code.  The runner is running on an intel MAC and the executioner is shell.  Not sure what I am missing.  When I run this same image locally and login to it I am able to find the package yamllint, but when it run through the pipeline, I keep getting:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package yamllint
```

```
Code-Check:
  stage: code-check
  variables:
    DOCKER_IMAGE: "python:3.8-slim"
  image: $DOCKER_IMAGE
  script:
    - docker run -v $(pwd):/app -w /app $DOCKER_IMAGE apt-get update -qy
    - docker run -v $(pwd):/app -w /app $DOCKER_IMAGE apt install yamllint
    - docker run -v $(pwd):/app -w /app $DOCKER_IMAGE yamllint . --strict > yamllint_report.txt || true
    - docker run -v $(pwd):/app -w /app $DOCKER_IMAGE find . -name "*.py" -exec bandit -r {} \; > bandit_report.txt || true
    - cat yamllint_report.txt
    - cat bandit_report.txt
  only:
    - branches
```

Comment: When you do this locally are you terminating and starting a new container for each command? or are you starting a container and running the 4 ocommands? in your example, when you run yaml lint, its in a new container thats not had apt update or the apt install run

Comment: In the given script ,you are creating 4 independent containers from  `$DOCKER_IMAGE`.   You need to run all those commands within the *same* docker container.  The most straightforward way to do it would be to do a Docker Build that runs the apt commands, then run that image to run the linters.  (add --rm to the `docker run` to remove the container when it's done).

Comment: You can run `yamllint` and `bandit` in the same image which will be faster and conserve resources.  You're mounting `/app` so you can just as easily do the output redirection to file within the container as outside the docker.   Easiest way, to include in your new dockerfile an entrypoint script that handles executing those things.  `|| true` what you probably want is to fail the job if either (or both) of those commands fail, but attempt to run both of them regardless of whether the other one fails.

Answer (score 0):

Set up `.gitlab-ci.yml` like this:

```
stages:
  - code-check

code-check:
  image: python:3.8-slim
  stage: code-check
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq -y
    - apt install -qq -y yamllint
    - pip install bandit
    - yamllint . --strict > yamllint_report.txt || true
    - find . -name "*.py" -exec bandit -r {} \; > bandit_report.txt || true
    - cat yamllint_report.txt
    - cat bandit_report.txt
```

In your version each of the steps was happening in a separate Docker container. So you installed `yamllint` in one container and then tried to run it in another (where it had not yet been installed).

With this approach everything happens in a single container.

Here's the end of the workflow logs directly off Gitlab:

[image]